# Hazelcast process flow

Tags: java, cluster-computing, hazelcast

My supervisor asked me to use Hazelcast for one of our java programs that takes 24 hours to processs huge txt file (2 GB or more).
I looked at the documentation from Hazelcast website, but my head is spinning so badly, i could not understand things described there.
I am not very competent programmer in java. I am a web developer. What are the steps if i need to run my java program in Hazelcast?

I will greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5):

it depends of your use case. See nice screencast here: http://hazelcast.com/screencast.jsp
Also there are some examples at hazelcast website.
Basically, you need to setup communication settings (jms/tcp-ip etc) and start your program at each node with these parameters, after it you can use all Hazelcast features (distributed maps, locks etc).